# Delete ONLY folders and his Files but don't do it in to another path PowerShell

Tags: backup

I try to delete in a path ONLY the Folder older than 7 days
But in the same path there are folders which inside them have files  older the 7 Days and i want to keep these.
Example:

```
C:\BACKUP\BAK_15-04-2020\some_files
C:\BACKUP\BAK_14-04-2020\some_files
C:\BACKUP\BAK_13-04-2020\some_files
C:\BACKUP\BAK_12-04-2020\some_files
C:\BACKUP\BAK_11-04-2020\some_files
C:\BACKUP\BAK_10-04-2020\some_files
```

Basically i want to delete ONLY the folder and his   content 
e.g. C\BACKUP\BAK 10-04-2020

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is easy to test in steps. First, we want to list only directories in C:\BACKUP:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\BACKUP -Directory

Directory: C:\BACKUP


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        16-Dec-19  11:33 AM                folder2019
d-----        19-May-20  10:09 AM                folder2020
```

But we don't want just any folder, we want folders older than 7 days. Luckily PowerShell lets us use Format-List to examine an object:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\BACKUP -Directory | Format-List
Name           : folder2019
CreationTime   : 05-Aug-19 5:03:57 PM
LastWriteTime  : 16-Dec-19 11:33:34 AM
LastAccessTime : 16-Dec-19 11:33:34 AM
Mode           : d-----
LinkType       :
Target         : {}
```

LastWriteTime seems like a good filter. We need a date time object to compare so we use Get-Date for the current date minus 7.

```
PS C:\> $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\BACKUP -Directory | where LastWriteTime -lt "$limit"

Directory: C:\BACKUP


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        16-Dec-19  11:33 AM                folder2019
```

And just listing the directory is not that useful so let's delete it:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\BACKUP -Directory | where LastWriteTime -lt "$limit" | Remove-Item
```

As always when deleting stuff, run it without the Remove-Item to verify the logic is sound.

Comment: Hello I am indebted for your prompt reply...!!!
But my problem now is: Before deleting the "FOLDER"the powershell waiting for input user answer:  [Yes, YesAll, No, NoAll,  etc] May I to do this automatically without the user acting???

Comment: You can set it to -Confirm:$false or you can use the -Force parameter depending on why you get the prompt to confirm.